# Battery powered High speed sync with Led continous

Tags: flash, lighting, off-camera-flash, high-speed-sync, led-lighting

Are there such a thing?
A High speed sync flash  for photography 
And it also work as led continous  for film
And it should be battery powered .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about specifics of availability... but sure, there should be battery powered continuous lights.

Basic principle:    Continuous light (sunlight, incandescent, or LED) has no sync speed limit...  Continuous light all works as "High Speed Sync" at any shutter speed.  That is what HSS is, is that the speedlight is converted to flash very rapidly (tens of thousands of times per second) to simulate continuous light.  Then there is no sync concern, any shutter speed works (as in daylight for example). High Speed Sync rapid flashing is technically a big deal to create, but the principle is simply a name, continuous light has no sync concerns.   Simply because that light is continuous.  Any shutter speed works, including high speed shutters.

Fast shutter speeds do drastically reduce the continuous exposure (same as daylight does), but opening the aperture to Equivalent Exposures compensates for the shutter speed falloff.  Because it is continuous.

Fluorescent is possibly an exception, continuous except older magnetic ballast lights flicker slowly (with AC line voltage cycles), and higher speed shutters won't work well.  We are advised to exactly match the shutter speed to the AC voltage frequency to avoid seeing random intensity and color variations.

However CFL bulbs and other electronic ballast flickers extremely fast (tens of thousands of times per second), and so does work at higher shutter speeds.

Comment: Thankfully there is no need to manually match fluorescent flicker anymore on newer cameras. Canon introduced anti-flicker on cameras like the 1DXII, 7DII, 80D, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are speedlights capable of HSS while also including continuous LED light for video shooting.  These will, however, be proprietary same-brand flashes, and are liable to be more expensive, and, in the case of Canon and Nikon, is a lower-powered flash (320EX, SB-500).

Generally, you get two different devices: either an HSS speedlight, or an LED panel, depending on your usage, since you're unlikely to be shooting stills at the same time you're shooting video with a single camera.

However, neither source of light is particularly powerful, btw, and will be limited in its usefulness, and become more limited the faster the shutter speed you use. Which is why most folks opt for other alternatives, such as ND filters on the lens with a non-HSS speedlight, or a larger video-dedicated LED panel or more powerful continuous light source instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Rotolight Anova Pro](https://www.rotolight.com/product/anova-pro) is a battery powered LED light that can actually double as a flash with High Speed Sync (HSS).  It's quite expensive.  Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iI44U_8_9MI) demonstrating the light's HSS capability.